# subdomain pointing to domain when using www

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

I'm facing the following issue, I've created a subdomain using a CNAME for a domain I have.

To put it simple:

```
subdomain   CNAME   domain
```

The following rules are also relevant:

```
www    CNAME    domain
@      A        1.2.3.4
```

Now the weird thing, is that when I point to www.subdomain.domain I get 404. When I point to subdomain.domain I get the expected page, but when I point to www.domain.com I get the subdomain page, instead of the domain page. I'm using Apache, two VirtualHosts, nothing special...but I really don't know why using www.domain.com points to the subdomain! Any ideas?

Thanks!
Alex

EDIT: This the apache config for the domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/domain/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the file for the subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

# Server name
ServerName subdomain.domain.com

# Document root
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain/


</VirtualHost>
```

That said, I've also changed the CNAME, just realized I was putting the value uncorrectly, so now it goes like this:

```
Name        Type    Value
subdomain   CNAME   subdomain.domain.com
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your Apache configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

A CNAME "www" to "domain.com", and domain.com to 1.2.3.4

A CNAME "www" to "subdomain.domain.com", and subdomain.domain.com to 1.2.3.4

```
# Vhost file #1
ServerName domain.com
domain.com DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/

# Vhost file #2
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
subdomain.domain.com DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain/
```

A CNAME is nothing more than a forward to another domain, so www.domain.com would go to domain.com.

You can also make a A Record subdomain which is a subdomain that points to a IP address like this:

A, A record "domain.com" to 1.2.3.4
A, A record "www.domain.com" to 1.2.3.4

In that case you could do this in the first Vhost file

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

So people could use both but the "www.domain.com" and "domain.com" to end up at your IP address

Comment: HI, I've created both A records, one for my domain and my subdomain pointing to my same IP and 2 CNAMES "www", each pointing to domain and subdomain. This is not working "yet"...I'll wait for DNS, but looks like is not working so far...

Comment: Ok, I've created 2 A records, one for domain.com and another one for www.domain.com. Both poin to same IP (obviously). Added the ServerAlias www.domain.com and now using www.domain.com points effectively to domain.com page and subdomain.domain.com to subdomain page. Last thing that would be nice to get working is www.subdomain.domain.com to point to subdomain page :) Should I add another A records for subdomain.domain.com and www.subdomain.domain.com and add the ServerAlias in the subdomain vhost file?

Comment: Yes you can have a vhost with the Servername subdomain.domain.com and a ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

```
Name        Type    Value
subdomain   CNAME   subdomain.domain.com
```

This is currently actually pointing to `subdomain.domain.com.domain.com` because you're missing the trailing dot after `.com`

However adding the trailing dot will make it invalid since you're creating a loop by CNAME'ing `subdomain` to itself.